# how does a router knows what subnet to add to an ip address?

Tags: routes, ip

For example, lets say my home computer, which is connected to my Att DSL router, request to access a www.google.com website, first my web browser needs to convert my www.google.com dns name to an ip address. After it gets the google ip address, it sends out a http request to an http server.

My question is how does the Internet routers knows how to route this google ip address in reaching its final destination? In other words, how does the internet routers know how to determine the network id and the host id of this google ip address?

Sorry if my question is confusing as this knowledge is confusing to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer for this question is long. You can learn about it for years.

I will try to give my best answer, focusing the "layer 3" aspect of that question. Off course there are a lot of thing happening in other layers (If you aren't compatible with layers read about the OSI model).

There are some things you should know:

### Default Gateway

When the packet doesn't know where to go- it will automatically go to the network device default gateway.

### Border Gateway Protocol (BGP)

This default gateway on the internet router is determined by Routing Information Protocol. BGP is the most common routing protocol on the internet.
You can read about it. good luck with that.

### DNS TREE STRUCTURE (Hierarchy)

In the internet- we have whats called DNS tree structure.
It work in a way that when you router search for google.com, first he will search the ".com" Root Server. To be honest- your router will send the packet to its default gateway (your ISP), and your ISP will know the IP of this server.
This server will search for the "google" server. Once he will find him, the IP will return to your computer.

Happy Networking.